# Python - dictionary file not being updated

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am uploading this `dictionary`:

```
  p1 =  {'user1': {u'Codex': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0, u'Hey': 1.0}}
```

Into my `dir path`:

```
if os.path.exists('db/user1.json'):
    with open('user1.json', 'r+') as f:
        db = p1
        db = json.load(f)
        # increment track count
        updateTrackCounts(p1,value=1.0)
        #update json here
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        json.dump(p1, f)
```

And I have this update function:

```
def updateTrackCounts(d, value=0):
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(d[i], dict):
            updateTrackCounts(d[i], value)
        elif isinstance(d[i], float):
            d[i] += value
```

But if I upload a different `dict`, say:

```
p2 = {'user1': {, u'NEW :1.0, u'Codex': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0, u'Hey': 1.0}}
```

I end up with:

```
output = {'user1': {u'Codex': 2.0, u'Pyramid Song': 2.0, u'Hey': 2.0}}
```

Instead of desired:

```
output = {'user1': {, u'NEW :1.0, u'Codex': 2.0, u'Pyramid Song': 2.0, u'Hey': 2.0}}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually updating the object you loaded from the file. Name references do not point backward, once you rebind the name to a new object, the previous object is not affected by whatever action is carried out via the old reference.

Change:

```
db = p1
db = json.load(f)
```

To:

```
db = p1 = json.load(f)
```

Or you can use db, to keep a reference to the previous object if you need both:

```
db = p1
p1 = json.load(f)
```